# How to create static pure virtual methods in C++?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, static, virtual-functions

I am trying to organize one Visual Studio project that will contain all of my solutions to Project Euler problems ([Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/archives)). I want to have for every problem a separate directory (`problemX`) that will contain all the necessary files for the solution to this problem. The directory would also include one file called `ProblemX` (X being the number of the problem) and this file will be the 'main' file of the given problem. However, this is my problem: I want to create sort of a "template" for this file. I want the compiler to give me an error when I don't create a `solve()` function inside of the `ProblemX` file. How is this achievable? I know there do exist abstract classes in C++ and that I could create a parent class `Problem` with an abstract method `solve()` and then I could inherit from this class in my `ProblemX` files. However, this only works for non-static methods. I also want to have a main file from which I would be able to call the `solve()` method without instantiating every `ProblemX` class before calling the `solve()` method. How would I go about solving this? I am also open to other suggestions on how I should organize my solutions but I'd also like to know the solution to this problem as I may run into this problem in the future again.

Comment: There ain't no such thing as a static virtual method. The whole point of `virtual` is that the implementation is chosen based on the dynamic type of the object the function is called on. The whole point of `static` is that the function doesn't require an object to be called on.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea to me. Why not create a single executable per problem?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @IgorTandetnik I don't understand your explanation of what `virtual` means.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Actually, I don't know. I thought it would be too complicated. But I might give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you prefer calling `ProblemX::solve();` (which can't be `virtual`) over `ProblemX().solve();` (which can be `virtual`)? Example: https://godbolt.org/z/mfCqNZ

Comment: It's because I'm very new to C++ object oriented programming and I don't know what I'm doing, just trying to make the compiler compile what I wrote. The thing you sent me is actually exactly what I wanted, so thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code by Ted Lyngmo is exactly what I needed:

```
#include <iostream>

struct IProblem {
    virtual bool solve() = 0;
    virtual ~IProblem() = default;
};

struct Problem1 : IProblem {
    bool solve() override {
        return true;
    }
};

struct Problem2 : IProblem {
    bool solve() override {
        return false;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout
        << std::boolalpha
        << Problem1().solve() << '\n'
        << Problem2().solve() << '\n';
}
```